# System for personalized recommendation of user generated (non-shared) content

Tags: machine-learning, classification, predictive-models, recommender-system

I am having some trouble designing a recommender or predictor system for the following problem.

Consider a system where each user can create custom labels for content. I would like to recommend to each user, which label they might use for new content.

I think it's easiest to explain at the hand of an example, in this case, word tags for email:
`User A` might label email using their tags: `important`, `later`, `junk` etc.
`User B` might use completely different labels of their own creation: `work`, `home`, `family` etc.

Based on the content I would like to predict or recommend to the user their labels most likely suited to their content.
E.g. in the email example, for a new email, recommend to `User B` labels: `work`, `project` based on the content of the email.

A collaborative filtering approach to the problem (using all users and all known tags) would potentially recommend tags that are not the user's own for labeling content, i.e. recommend label `important` to `User B`, which is not a valid recommendation.

The only idea I have is to build/train a *personalized model for each user* based on their own data and labels.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first impression, one might think that user A labels (important, later, junk) may be somehow orthogonal to user B labels (work, home, family). If they really are, the collaborative filtering can't help. But actually even if they seem to be orthogonal, they may not be: hopefully junk is negatively correlated to family for example.

The collaborative approach will be especially useful when labels are correlated, typically user A (work, home, family) being essentially renaming of user B (job, house, wife&kids).

How can you know that "work" and "job" are the same labels? Hopefully, you can use the textual content of the mail: these labels tend to be used for similar mails. You can try to define a similarity between labels: two labels would be similar if correlated to the same words.

If you want to use a word/word method (like word2vec or SVD dimension reduction on word/word matrix) labels can be managed almost exactly like usual words of the mail: you just create bag of words that contain both words in the mail and labels, labels being possibly prefixed with "L[userID]_"  to avoid identifying them with the words and keeping the specificity of what the user means with his label.

These method will result in a distance between words/labels that can be used by the predictor. When reading a mail, you just compute the distance from each user's label to the words in the mail.

Comment: Thank you for the response. If the labels are textual, I think your approach would work, an model could learn the correlation between labels for each user and a suggestion could be made based on which label has the highest correlation.

In a more general sense, if labels are uncorrelated or can't be correlated (maybe the labels aren't words), is the only option left to create personalized models?

Comment: You don't need the labels to be words with this method. You just transform them into words  (that actually mean nothing and whose textual content is not used) as a trick in order to use the dimension reduction together with the real words. If the labels were IDs like "L248503", this would work just the same.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I haven't considered it like that. I will design an experiment to test the methodology, but will accept your answer in the mean time :-)